# Persistent volume claims vs subPath

Tags: kubernetes, storage

I would like to use a single mount point on a node (ie `/data`) and have a different sub folder for each `PersistentVolumeClaim` that I am going to use in my cluster.

At the moment I have multiple `StorageClass` and `PersistentVolume` for each sub folder, for example:

```yaml
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: prometheus
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: "/data/prometheus"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: disk
              operator: In
              values:
                - local
```

As you can image having a `StorageClass`, a `PersistentVolume` for each `PersistentVolumeClaim` looks a bit of an overkill.

I have tried to use a single `StorageClass` and `PersistentVolume` (just pointing to  `/data`), the `usePath` option (ie `prometheus`) with multiple `PersistentVolumeClaim`.
But I have noticed that if the `securityContext.fsGroupChangePolicy` option is enabled it will apply the user/group changes to root of the volume (ie `/data`) not to the `subPath` (ie `/data/prometheus`).

Is there a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[local-path-provisioner](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner) seems to be a good solution